# SQL Server could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'DOMAIN\user_account'

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have cloned our Microsoft SQL to a new server.  The server contains a few databases and "SQL Server Agent" jobs that run on a scheduled basis.  I have tried changing all existing references to this new server name and use accounts on this new server.  However I am still getting the following error in my error log and my jobs fails to run (btw, this is through Microsoft SQL Management Studio),

```
[298] SQLServer Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'DOMAIN\user_account', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)
```

I've got a couple of Maintenance Plans which are pointing to the old server.  For some unknown reason I can't edit the existing connection and I can't delete it.  I can add a new one but the other connection can not be removed.

I need to know where I need to change for this error to go away and the jobs start running.

Comment: That error can appear when the new SQL Server service is configured with the default `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` virtual account and the original SQL Server service was using an Active Directory domain account. Doesn't sound like you cloned all of the configuration you needed.

Answer (score 2):

This may be because SQL has the wrong server name in Master.  [Here is another article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208362/what-does-298-sqlserver-error-15404-could-not-obtain-information-about-windo) on the subject.

[SQL Server Central Article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/fixing-maintenance-plan-error-code-0x534)

In order to fix this, run a search on Master with the following code:

```
use master
select SERVERPROPERTY('servername')
select @@SERVERNAME
select SERVERPROPERTY('machinename')
go
```

If you see the old server name in the list you will have to drop the server and add the new one

```
use master
exec sp_dropserver "OldServerNmae"
go

use master
exec sp_addserver "NewServerName","local"
go
```